# turn by turn navigation: guide against one way road

Tags: here-api

I am working on a turn by turn navigation for public communities where some vehicles are allowed to drive against one way roads, or through pedestrian zones.
Can this functionality be achieved with the here maps navigation sdk?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, this is not a ready made solution provided in mobile sdk. But you can achieve this by adding custom routing extensions on top of our api and achieve the same. You read about Custom Route Extensions provided by Fleet Telematics API on Here developer site (developer.here.com/documentation/custom-routing-extension/topics/quick-start-block-a-road.html)